# Linux kernel header.S source, why _end+3 needed when zeroing BSS?

Tags: linux, assembly, linux-kernel, x86, bootloader

In the Linux source tree the file [arch/x86/boot/header.S](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/boot/header.S?v=3.19) has x86 code similar to this to clear the *BSS* section prior to `main` being called:

```
...
# Zero the bss
    movw    $__bss_start, %di
    movw    $_end+3, %cx
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    subw    %di, %cx
    shrw    $2, %cx
    rep; stosl
...
```

Why does the `_end` address have 3 added to it? Why not `movw $_end, %cx` instead of `movw $_end+3, %cx`?

Answer (score 7):

Had the code been clearing the *BSS* section byte by byte `movw $_end, %cx` would have sufficed. However, this code doesn't zero out the *BSS* with *STOSB* they use *STOSL*. It is generally more efficient to store 32 bits at a time rather than 8 bits.

[*STOSL*](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/STOS:STOSB:STOSW:STOSD:STOSQ.html) will store *EAX* (which is set to zero with `xorl %eax, %eax`) enough times to clear the entire range of *BSS* to 0. The +3 insures that if the length of the *BSS* section ($_end-$__bss_start) is not evenly divisible by 4, that computing the number of *DWORD*s needed to clear will be rounded up. If this rounding up doesn't occur then in instances where the size isn't evenly divisible by 4, the last bytes may not be cleared.

The calculation being done here assumes `__bss_start` is a pointer to the beginning of BSS segment and that `_end` is a pointer to the end of *BSS*. The equation to compute the number of 32-bit *DWORD*s to clear is effectively:

```
NUMDWORDS=(_end+3-__bss_start) >> 2
```

The `shrw $2, %cx` (`>>2` in the calculation) is integer division by 4 where the result is always rounded down. We add +3 to the number of bytes so that when the division by 4 is done it effectively rounds up to the nearest number of *DWORD*s. This value is then used as the number of *DWORD*s *STOSL* will be setting to zero.